# No module named Linq

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I wrote a python script to use in C#, but when I run my project this error occurs: "No module named Linq". what should I do? I took the import part from another part of project from TFS and it works well there, so what is going on?

```
import System
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference(''System.Core'')
from System import Array
from System import DateTime
from System.Linq import Enumerable
from System import Func
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your single vs double quotes.

But try "ImportExtensions"

```
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
```

Comment: the single quote is because I store the python script in Sql and that is not the problem. but the ImportExtensions worked! thanks a lot

Comment: Im testing my project and now I get this Error: attribute 'Linq' of 'namespace#' object is read-only